# Neural Networks Time Series Classification

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series

I just started reading about neural nets, and stumbled upon an intersting project from this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122113000291) which i'm trying to replicate using Keras in python.

I'm stuck a bit on underinging the issue on a High-Level. My question is regarding what exactly the input features in a time series in such a case are. what i'm trying to do is classify very specific patterns in a time series (of unknown lenght), in this case is each value in the time series a feature (so if i have 10 points i have 10 nodes in my input) or is it a 1D array with the values?

In the paper it seems that each input node represents a specific point in time, but what doesn't make sense is that if this is the proper setup, how do i deal if my time series has 10+ points (obviously i can't dynamically add nodes).

Just need a bit of guidance as i am not sure where to look for an answer.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a naive approach usually used in regression solutions is to either transform timeseries info to features (eg. hour of day(1-24)/day of the week/week of the year, depending what's relevant), or even more simplistically keep a feature with the timestamp.

Comment: I'm not sure i need the timestamp as a feature. In my case i'm just trying to detect a pattern. From what i understand this has nothing to do with date/time (since the interval is conastant)